# Bitset with size unknown at compile time

Tags: c++

I know that initializing an object of the bitset class means you have to use a compile-time constant for the number of bits. However, for my purposes, I want to a produces a giant array of boolean values and I know I could save memory by using the bitset class if only it weren't the case that the size of this array is known only at run time. Is there a way around this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset - look at the notes at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic_bitset from boost

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html

or vector< bool > specialization from STL

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

all depends on your requirements, such as the operators and functions that you need

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to boost you can use its dynamic_bitset:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html